# Splitting a String at Char in Painless Scripting Language

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to split a String (that represents an IPv4 address) in painless. I tried the following:

```
String[] ipAddressParts = /\\./.split(params.ip);
```

But the String doesn't get split at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, the correct code is this one (you have one too many backslashes):

```
String[] ipAddressParts = /\./.split(params.ip);
```

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much. It finally works! :)