# Extracting and aggregating text values from a field with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation

Im new to ElasticSearch, and my first mission is as follow:
Here is the beginning of my query:

```
  "_source": "pageVisitsValues",
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "blockSize": 30
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "pageViews": {
                  "from": 1,
                  "to": null,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": {
                      "regexp": {
                        "pageVisitsValues": {
                          "value": ".*utm_medium=.*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Utm_term1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pageVisitsValues",
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    },
```

now here is part of the result:

```
"hits": { - 
    "total": 204223,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [ - 
      { - 
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "AX45WhAzfmq",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": { - 
          "pageVisitsValues": [ - 
            "www.test.com/search?&q=bullion deals&utm_source=iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=weeklydeals"
          ]
        }
      },
      { - 
        "_index": "8767827_all_25216812968619266m",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "AX45vDJEamKugpqPWxqJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": { - 
          "pageVisitsValues": [ - 
            "www.mytestsite.com/search?&q=indian",
            "www.mytestsite.com/search?&q=indianhead cents&rows=80&view=grid&version=v2&start=160",
            "www.mytestsite.com/product/24158/1867-indianvg",
            "www.mytestsite.com/search?q=&x=11&y=7&silver&page=1&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=cpa&utm_term=testx&utm_content=test",
            "www.mytestsite.com/product/233871/flying-eagle-indian-head-cent-1856-1909",
            "www.mytestsite.com/search?&q=silver eagles bu"
          ]
        }
      },
      { - 
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "userID",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": { - 
          "pageVisitsValues": [ - 
            "www.mytestsite.com/product/1/bu-random-year?utm_source=criteo&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=prospecting&dclid=cpyz4_j54fqcfcdbpaqd0dkkiw"
          ]
        }
}
```

what I need to do is to find a way to aggregate all "utm_medium" values from the "pageVisitsValues" field, so my expected result should be something like this:

```
Utm_term1": { - 
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 426,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 1557591,
      "buckets": [ - 
        { - 
          "key": "email",
          "doc_count": 31283
        },
        { - 
          "key": "cpc",
          "doc_count": 23615
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: How are you writing this data into Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a new list to ES and aggregating on it since it would be less expensive, but if you don't want to do that, you can create a dynamic variable per record `runtime_mappings` and do a term aggregation on it, check the script section in the [official docs for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values).

To extract the keyword needed using painless script, you can use the `.split` function, check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243184/splitting-a-string-at-char-in-painless-scripting-language) out.

If you need any further help please reply to this comment.

Comment: Hey Rama, thanks for your help.
Unfortunately, we are using a very old ES version, so we decided to just create a new mapping and index the UTM values instead of running a script for every query.